# Auto-Hide Taskbar Malfunction...?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

I like to keep my taskbar hidden when it's not in use as to get my screen the ultimate space it can have, but sometimes after long periods of PC use, the taskbar glitches (I think it's a glitch) and although it's set to 'hide' it stays visible whilst overlapping whatever window happens to be open and there is no fixing this other than turning off auto-hide where the window will then realign to be under the taskbar or over it - for me, under as I prefer to have my taskbar on the top portion of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that a program is notifying you and the program on the list will turn a orange yellow color and if you click the program then minimize it the task bar should go down.

PS. This happens to me all the time.

Comment: This does not work for me.